# ZF2 Configuration Injection Or NOT?

Tags: configuration, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I've googled a lot and read as much as I can on the subject but I cannot find a direct answer to my question anywhere including here.  My ZF2 application consists of roughly 7 different modules.  5 of the modules will need access to the same database configuration.  The application itself has a database with roughly 124 different tables.  So the idea here is to find the proper solution to write the least amount of code considering the setup.

What I'm trying to do is create a specific class to interface with the DB.  Where the business logic is kept in the Module and note the controllers to keep everything more abstract and easier to maintain.  By that I mean controller X should be able to create a new instance of for instance (Application\Model\DBInterface) and use the models functions to do inserts deletes updates joins selects and so forth.  The reason I would like to do it this way is so that all modules installed can use the same interface without having to write endless DI statements everywhere.  So what I will need is an example of how I can get the configuration for the DB (currently inside module.config.php + local.php(username / pw)) to be passed to the Application\Model\DBInterface dbConfig variable, and perhaps even an instance of the dbAdapter initialized from config if possible.

Alternatively I could potentially grab the configuration from the Application\Model\DBInterface if such a way exists.

If neither of the above is possible then I can always go back to the old way of doing things by reading an ini file for the db details and instantiating my db adapter that way.

Please keep in mind that I won't be injecting anything in the controllers as the controllers just *use* $db = new \Application\Model\DBInterface() so injecting into the controllers doesn't make much sense at all.

Is there a better way to do this / optimized / am I doing it completely wrong?  Anyone able to share some details please.  I've spent way too much time on this already and definitely need help.

Comment: Once DI is setup, I recommend injecting *every* service. (Not everything is a service, but the DB access surely is! Then again, I only use DI in a statically typed environment so I don't need to worry about using the icky "Service Locator Pattern".)

Comment: How do you setup the DI for this though that's the question?  I've seen countless articles on injecting to controllers which also means that you have to add di to each controller handling the 124 different tables.  Right now doesn't seem like a very scalable solution to use di unless I'm completely misunderstanding

Comment: I don't know how DI in PHP works, but if done right, it should be *less* complicated than using `new`s over the place. Once it's used anywhere, the cost of adding to any specific service should be trivial. It might be worthwhile into looking for a generator if the CRUD is predictable.

Comment: Check ServiceLocatorAwareInterface. If implemented, you can read your dbConfig in your DBInterface class and use the same adapter as well. (I may be wrong too)

Comment: @Pradeep Service Locators are to DI as the Singleton is to OOP :( Surely PHP has a better approach for this?

Comment: @Will you sure dont want to instantiate your DBInterface through the service locator?

Comment: @pst its all about Zend and figuring out what their docs does not say at this point of time.

Comment: @Pradeep I wouldn't mind instantiating it through the service locator, but I can't seem to find any decent examples on how to implement and then use the interface across all modules.  I'll take a look to see if I can figure something out.  If you have an example handy I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I would always instantiate such things via service locator (or inject attributes). Direct instantiation means you have to handle the dependencies yourself, and that's not a problem of your controller.

Comment: @WillH Did you try out my answer? As far as i understand your problem, this pretty much solves all your problems. If not, please specify what problem still occurs with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so @Ocramius did just let me know what my misconception with the `initializers` was and helped me out a bit in understanding it. So here is a probably working solution to your Problem. My understanding about your problem is:

**"How to get a DbAdapter set for all your Models implementing a DbInterface"**. This is how you'd do it:

---

**Step 1:** Create `invokables` for all classes implementing the `DbInterface`. Create a `factory` for the default `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` and then create an `initializer` for your `DbInterface`

**Module.php `getServiceConfig()`**

```
return array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'application-model-one' => 'Application\Model\One',
        'application-model-two' => 'Application\Model\Two'
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory'
    ),
    'initializers' => array( 
        'DbInterfaceInitializer' => function($instance, $sm) {
            if ($instance instanceof \Application\Model\DBInterface) {
                $instance->setDbAdapter($sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'));
            }
        },
    )
)
```

The **Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter** is using the top-level-configuration-array-key `'db'` to automatically inject the dbParams

---

**Step 2:** Create your classes implementing your Interface

**Application\Model(One|Two|N).php**

```
namespace Application\Model;

class One implements DbInterface, \Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter $dbAdapter
     */
    protected $dbAdapter;

    public function setDbAdapter(\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter $dbAdapter) {
        $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    }

    public function getDbAdapter() {
        return $this->dbAdapter;
    }

    // More of your business logic or data here
}
```

---

**Step 3:** Access those classes with the ServiceLocator from your Controllers

**SomeController.php `someAction()`**

```
$dbOne = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('application-model-one');
$dbTwo = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('application-model-two');
// Adapter will automatically be injected
```

When accessing the `invokable` from the ServiceManager the `initializer` will be called. The initializer then will automatically call the `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter`, which in turn get's the parameters from the configuration key `'db'`

---

You may get more information from once [the tutorial Application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable) as well as the blog of 
[samsonasik: ServiceManager Cheat-Sheet](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/zend-framework-2-cheat-sheet-service-manager/)

Comment: @Ocramius alright ;) Before removing this answer, do you have the time to explain initializers in a sentence or two then?

Comment: Even though your answer got voted down I think this question has given some of the best information about the general question that I have found anywhere.  @Ocramius, if you can provide a better solution please do... Otherwise I will be happy to test out Sam's solution and give him proper credit for providing a working solution even though it's not best practice it does seem to answer the question.

Comment: @WillH it was actually me downvoting this one, but also I didn't notice it was modified. I am removing my comment to avoid confusion in future readers and upvoting (I didn't provide a better solution because I personally hate initializers).

Comment: @Ocramius any particular reason you hate initializers? Would be nice to know of any potential pitfalls etc.

Comment: @WillH `'a' => function ($sl) { $a = new A(); $a->setFoo($sl->get('foo')); return $a; }`. Then define an initializer that calls `$a->setFoo()` and you broke everything (not even debuggable). There's also a performance drop and a testability decrease.

Comment: Great for the info on that.  Hopefully that would also help future readers.