# ZF2 dependency injection in parent

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I want to call the method SteeringWheelMapper->fetchCarBrandList() from a controller.
This works good now, but there's a problem.

The SteeringWheelMapper extends the AbstractWebServiceMapper which has a construct method which requires an instance of \Zend\Http\Client.

As you can see in my module.config.php file, I use "factories" for the instantiation of my SteeringWheelMapper.
The supplier has multiple products, so I will have to build multiple mappers. In the current situation that means I have to add a key to the factories config for every mapper which extends AbstractWebServiceMapper.

For example, when I want to add an ExhaustMapper, I have to add

```
SupplierName\Mapper\Exhaust => function ($serviceMapper) {
    $httpClient => new \Zend\Http\Client;

    return new SupplierName\Mapper\ExhaustMapper($httpClient);
}
```

Now I am repeating myself, because I also have to do this for SupplierName\Mapper\SteeringWheelMapper.

I think there should be a way to make a factory for all the mappers, instead of a new key added to the factories config. 
Is my thought right? 
Does anyone has a suggestion how I should do this?

Please see code below.

I'm using ZF2 and I use this setup:
/vendor

- SupplierName

  - config

    - module.config.php
  - log

    - log.log
  - src

    - SupplierName

      - Entity

        - AbstractEntity.php
        - SteeringWheelEntity.php
      - Mapper

        - AbstractWebServiceMapper.php
        - SteeringWheelMapper.php

  $steeringWheelMapper = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('SupplierName\Mapper\SteeringWheel');
  $carBrandList = $steeringWheelMapper->fetchCarBrandsList();

SteeringWheelMapper.php

```
<?php

namespace SupplierName\Mapper;

class SteeringWheelMapper extends AbstractWebServiceMapper
{   
    public function fetchCarBrandList()
    {
        // Code for request

        // Dispatch HTTP request
        $this->dispatch();
    }
}
```

My SupplierName/config/module.config.php looks like this:

```
<?php

return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'SupplierName\Mapper\SteeringWheel' => function ($serviceManager) {
                $httpClient = new \Zend\Http\Client;

                return new SupplierName\Mapper\SteeringWheelMapper($httpClient);
            },
        ),
    ),
    'supplier_name' => array(
        'api' => array(
            'url' => 'http://api.example.com',
        ),
        'log' => array(
            'file_location' => __DIR__ . '/../log/log.log',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: I think you're pretty much looking for something i did there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843351/zf2-configuration-injection-or-not/14848840#14848840

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually talking about is an abstract factory, the service manager supports the concept, but you'll need to write your own, here's an example that assumes all your mappers begin with `SupplierName\Mapper`

```
<?php
namespace SupplierName\Services;

use Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class MapperAbstractFactory implements AbstractFactoryInterface
{
    public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        if (0 === strpos($requestedName, 'SupplierName\\Mapper') && class_exists($requestedName)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function createServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $httpClient = new \Zend\Http\Client;

        return new $requestedName($httpClient);
    }
}
```

In your service config, add an abstract factories key, along with the fqcn of the abstract factory, and hopefully any time you call `$sm->get('SupplierName\Mapper\SomeClass');` providing the class exists, you'll get a composed instance returned

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{       
    return array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(    
            'SupplierName\Services\MapperAbstractFactory'
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! After some minor changes it worked. I've posted the final working solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Final working solution:

```
<?php
// module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $translator;

    public function __construct(Translator $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {                
        $steeringWheelMapper = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('SupplierName\Mapper\SteeringWheel');
        $carBrandList = $steeringWheelMapper->fetchCarBrandList();

        return new ViewModel();
    }
```

### }

```
<?php
// vendor/SupplierName/src/SupplierName/Module.php

namespace SupplierName;

class Module
{    
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../../config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {   
        return array(
            'abstract_factories' => array(    
                'SupplierName\Mapper\MapperAbstractFactory'
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
```

### }

```
<?php
// vendor/SupplierName/src/SupplierName/Mapper/SteeringWheelMapper.php

namespace SupplierName\Mapper;

class SteeringWheelMapper extends AbstractWebServiceMapper
{   
    public function fetchCarBrandList()
    {
        $this->dispatch();
    }
}

<?php
// vendor/SupplierName/src/SupplierName/Mapper/AbstractWebServiceMapper.php

namespace SupplierName\Mapper;

use \Zend\Http\Client;

class AbstractWebServiceMapper
{
    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {

    }

    public function dispatch()
    {       

    }
```

### }

```
<?php
// vendor/SupplierName/src/SupplierName/Mapper/MapperAbstractFactory.php
namespace SupplierName\Mapper;

use Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

use \Zend\Http\Client;

class MapperAbstractFactory implements AbstractFactoryInterface
{
    public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName)
    {    
        if (0 === strpos($requestedName, 'SupplierName\Mapper')) {
            $requestedName .= 'Mapper';

            if (class_exists($requestedName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function createServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $requestedName .= 'Mapper';

        $httpClient = new Client();

        return new $requestedName($httpClient);
    }
}
```